# Is my recurrence relation correct for mixture formation?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

Harry Potter has n mixtures in front of him, arranged in a row.Each mixture has one of 100 different colors (colors have numbers from 0 to 99).
He wants to mix all these mixtures together. At each step, he is going to take two mixtures that stand next to each other and mix them together, and put the resulting mixture in their place.
When mixing two mixtures of colors a and b, the resulting mixture will have the color (a+b) mod 100.
Also, there will be some smoke in the process. The amount of smoke generated when mixing two mixtures of colors a and b is a*b.
Find out what is the minimum amount of smoke that Harry can get when mixing all the ixtures together.
Input

For k change from i to j
Dp[i,j] = min(dp[i, k] + dp[k+1, j] + cost of mixing the resulting mixture)

Comment: Homework? Assignment?

Comment: @abhay: asked in interview.

Comment: I don't know why this is given -1? Why do people assume this is homework problem?

Answer (score 0):

The way to think about is `k` is the variable that tells you where the split point is where the last mix took place to form a single potion from `i..j` inclusive.

I think your recurrence has some off by one errors. Are `i` and `j` inclusive? Then `k` should stop at `j-1`, not `j`.

Comment: Yes k should stop 1 element before j and i and j is inclusive